# Plotting GIF on Folium Map

Tags: python, gis, folium

I have a GIF of 24 seconds showing the temperature of `-119.564209,38.503915,-114.060059,41.211203` region in the square (heat map) for 24 hrs. Is there a way I can plot this GIF on the Folium map (or any other interactive map in python) by giving the mentioned coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it using folium.

```
from folium import raster_layers
m = folium.Map(location=[100, 100], zoom_start=2, tiles='OpenStreetMap')

raster_layers.ImageOverlay('temp.gif',
                    [[-119.564209,38.503915],[-114.060059,41.211203]],
                    opacity=0.8,
                   ).add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```